# How do I sort a dictionary by the occurrence of the word NOT alphabetically in python

Tags: python, string, sorting, dictionary, frequency

I am new to coding and I am starting with python. I am trying to sort dictinary by the occurrence of the word. here is the code i am using

```
lis = ['Now when I am faced with a new situation I am not so nervous.'] 
for word in lis:

      word = word.strip()
      word = word.lower()
      each = word.split(" ")

for p in each:
      lis.append(p)

d = {}


for p in lis:
    if p in d:
        d[p] = d[p] + 1
    else:
        d[p] = 1

for c in sorted(d):
    print(c, d[c])
```

here is the result, i am getting alphabetically

```
a 1
am 2
faced 1
i 2
nervous. 1
new 1
not 1
now 1
situation 1
so 1
when 1
with 1
```

and here is the result I am trying to get. ordered or sorted by the frequency of the word.
as you can see start with the biggest number which in this case 2.

```
i 2
am 2
now 1
when 1
faced 1
with 1
a 1
new 1
situation 1
not 1
so 1
nervous 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and its method `most_common`:

```py
from collections import Counter

lis = ['Now when I am faced with a new situation I am not so nervous.']

counter = Counter(word.strip('.').lower() for word in lis[0].split())

for word, c in counter.most_common():
    print(f"{word} {c}")

# i 2
# am 2
# now 1
# when 1
# faced 1
# with 1
# a 1
# new 1
# situation 1
# not 1
# so 1
# nervous 1
```

If you want to implement it manually, you can use `sorted` with `key` parameter:

```py
for word, c in sorted(counter.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True):
    print(f"{word} {c}")
```

Note that this also applies to your manually constructed dict `d`.